# PHP Problemas con la lógica

Tags: php

Muy buenas tardes Titanes de la programación, me a surgido un gran problema, estoy haciendo un pequeño formulario de pedidos de una carta de Comidas

[image: Formulario]

los botones con forma de x y + son checkbox y a su costado tengo un select con la cantidad de veces que quiero pedir el mismo producto.

Aquí les muestro el siguiente código `PHP` lo que hago es tomar 3 variables que tomo de un AJAX, ahi les pongo el valor que tiene

```
$nromesa = $_POST['xnromesa'];//esta variable tiene un valor de '12'
$pedidos = $_POST['xpedidos'];//esto es un array con valor de '1,3,5'
$idgrupo = $_POST['xidgrupo'];//esta variable tiene un valor de '25'

foreach ($pedidos as &$nropedido) { 
    $Modal = $RestControll->EnviarPedido($nromesa, $idgrupo, $nropedido);
    //primer loop: (12,25,1)
    //segundo loop: (12,25,3)
    //tercer loop: (12,25,5)
}

unset($nropedido); // rompe la referencia con el último elemento
```

Hasta ahi funciona la parte de tomar esas variables y luego mandarlas a mi capa modelo para guardar esos datos en mi bd, mi problema surge cuando quiero agregar un nuevo dato que seria la cantidad de veces que quiero un mismo producto

estuve pensando como hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
$cantidadplatos = $_POST['xcantidadplatos'];//esto es un array con valor de '1,0,1,0,2' , los 0 son los guiones que salen en la imagen de arriba dentro del select

    foreach ($cantidadplatos as &$nroplatos) {  
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $nroplatos; $i++) //al contar al partir del 1 ya no va a tomar los valores de 0 dentro del array $nroplatos
        {
            echo "$i";
            //primer loop: (1);
            //segundo loop: (1);
            //tercer loop: (1,2);
        }
    }
```

pero el problema es que esto de arriba no soluciona el problema de enviar la cantidad de platos que necesito, por ejemplo en la pizza debería enviarse 2 veces a la capa modelo para que luego lo guarde en la bd.

no se si me explico bien, por favor si algo no les queda claro preguntenme.

Alguien quería mi tabla así que aquí se la muestro:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | integer     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| codpro   | integer     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| grupo    | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| mesa     | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cliente  | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Y aquí les muestro como lo inserto a la tabla por si las dudas

```
public function EPedido($nromesa, $idgrupo, $nropedido)
    {
        $Conexion = $this->Bd->connect();
        $ResultSet = $Conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO pedidos (codpro, grupo, mesa) VALUES (:codpro, :idgrupo, :mesa)");
        $ResultSet->execute(array(
        "codpro" => "$nropedido",
        "mesa" => "$nromesa",
        "idgrupo" => "$idgrupo"
        ));
        return $ResultSet;
    }
```

Comment: Almacenas la cantidad de pedidos en que tabla, muestra tu db.

Comment: Listo, ya modifique

Comment: que es codpro en esa tabla?

Comment: codpro, es el id del pedido, necesito ese dato por que en otra vista hago un innerjoin entre la tabla de productos y pedidos

Comment: ah genial.. y los productos que se piden van en la tabla de pedidos? no deberias recibir un array que diga codigo de producto y cantidad?

Comment: Si, los productos que se van pidiendo van a la tabla pedidos, esta tabla pedidos es un historial de todos los pedidos que se hacen, y si el array del código del producto ya esta es esa variable que se llama $pedidos, y también la cantidad esta ahí es esa que puse como yo creía que se podía solucionar la cual se llama $cantidadplatos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno la solución estaba en el AJAX

```
function postPedidos() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var arr_pedido = [];
    $('.chk_pedido:checked').each(function(){
        var pedido = {};
        pedido.id = $(this).val();
        pedido.cant_platos = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cantidadplatos option:selected').val(); 
        arr_pedido.push(pedido);
    });
    var nromesa = $(".mesa_nro").val();
    var idgrupo = $("#lista_Pedidos").val();
    console.log(arr_pedido);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'EnviarPedido.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            xnromesa: nromesa,
            xpedidos: arr_pedido,
            xidgrupo: idgrupo
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function() {
            alertify.set({ delay: 2300 });
            alertify.error("Error en la conexión a la BD");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                alertify.set({ delay: 2300 });
                alertify.success("Pedido Registrado");
                modalLiberado();
            } else {
                alertify.set({ delay: 2300 });
                alertify.error("Pedido Error");
            }
        }
    });
```

Y en el PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');//ESTO LO USO PARA QUE ME MUESTRE TODOS LOS ERRORES

require_once '../Controlador/RestaurantController.php';//
$nromesa = $_POST['xnromesa'];//TOMO LA VARIABLE DEL JS 8
$pedidos = $_POST['xpedidos'];
$idgrupo = $_POST['xidgrupo'];
$RestControll = new RestaurantController;

foreach ($pedidos as $nropedido) {  
    for($i = 0; $i < $nropedido['cant_platos']; $i++ ){
        $Modal = $RestControll->EnviarPedido($nromesa, $idgrupo, $nropedido['id']);
    }
}

unset($nropedido); // rompe la referencia con el último elemento


if($Modal)
{
    echo "1";
}
else
{
    echo "0";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que te muestra todos los productos y q probablemente al meter la orden existan campos que no esten llenos, te recomiendo que primero muestre solo los productos q vas a vender.

yo por ejemplo lo hice una vez dejando que el nombre del campo de la cantidad sea igual al nombre del item a vender. entonces seria algo como $_POST[PIZZA] = 2.
sacas el key y ese sera el item y ya tienes la cantidad..

Answer (score 0):

Ese bucle foreach que contiende dentro un for es ineficiente e innecesario.
En el array de cantidad de platos tu ya tienes la cantidad de platos que se necesitan.
Lo que deberías hacer en el foreach es comprobar con un If si es mayor que 0, y en ese caso, hacer la inserción en BD. 
De esta manera solo haces una inserción y eliminas el bucle for de dentro del foreach que es totalmente innecesario.